# How to start application at a particular time?

Tags: scheduled-tasks, utorrent

I am downloading a file from uTorrent. The file is approximately 10GB. But the problem is I want to start the application at a particular time, not the downloading. I know about the scheduler function in uTorrent, but it will only work when the application is on. Some of the users just come and exit uTorrent, so I am unable to download my files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know utorrent only runs on windows so..

You have to use the *"Task Scheduler"*
 [How to Create a Automated Task that Runs at a Set Time in Windows 7](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/12444-task-scheduler-create-new-task.html)

<sub>For people running linux, Mac or BSD have a look at [cron](http://clickmojo.com/code/cron-tutorial.html)</sub>

Comment: The link you gave gave me a message i.e. Sorry, the board is unavailable

We will be back in a few minutes...

Comment: @FrozenKing - well it works now

Answer (score 0):

You should use Task Scheduler to start any program at some particular time. In case anyone exits uTorrent it does not effect the Task Scheduler. Run Task Scheduler, click on *Create a task* and then configure your task. You can also trigger it at any time you want.

Answer (score 0):

I use ProManager on my server, it can start or stop selected apps at a predetermined time interval. Has a detailed log and some other features. It helped me in a similar problem.

Description and download: http://www.basicsoft.net/products.html