# Windows: Restart application at a specific time?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
>   [How to start application on a particular time?](https://superuser.com/questions/385877/how-to-start-application-on-a-particular-time)

I have a buggy Windows application that has a memory leak. I need a program that will restart the application at 1:30 pm every day before the memory leak starts slowing down the system. So the program would check to see if the an instance of the process is running and if so, kill it then restart it.

Is there anything out there that will accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use [Windows Task Scheduler](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721871.aspx). You would need to write a program to check, kill and restart if necessary though, but that should be easy enough via a script.

Answer (score 0):

This question was asked previously also. Check out the answer in this link.

[How to start application at a particular time?](https://superuser.com/questions/385877/how-to-start-application-on-a-particular-time)

Comment: rather than post this as an answer, you should flag this question for a moderator to have it marked as a duplicate.